# How do you format dropdown menus with google's css?

Tags: html, css, google-sheets

I'm using

`link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css`

to format the html served in a google spreadsheet script with HtmlService.  This formats a "select" input element, but the dropdown menu seems to still be the system default.  Is there a way around this?

If you use data validation of a custom range w/ dropdown in a google spreadsheet, the actual dropdown is also formatted.

How can I replicate this effect in my html file?

For reference, see this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XvORP0UuYHEepq--HWrNzzmWykCwLZa1F2lR63LTx2A/edit) and this code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<select name="selector" id="demoSelector">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Notice that the spreadsheet's google-formatted dropdown is square and under the selector, the code snippet generates a google-formatted dropdown, but the actual dropdown menu is formatted by your operating system defaults and appears on top of the selector.

Comment: I don't know your technique but my guess is that you need to use a script to convert native dropdown to "fancy" dropdown. Can you add a snippet or bin with your code? Also, add a link to formatted `select` demo so we could understand what do you mean by `dropdown is also formatted`

Comment: @MoshFeu examples added to question

Comment: And where the dropdown in the spreadsheet?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wXm5r.png ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104766/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-menasheh).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with css only, you need to use js too.

Here is an example with [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick). (There are many plugins you can use)

```js
$('#demoSelector').ddslick().change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.dd-select {
  background: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/disclosure/grey-disclosure-arrow-up-down.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/disclosure/grey-disclosure-arrow-up-down.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/disclosure/grey-disclosure-arrow-up-down.png), -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/disclosure/grey-disclosure-arrow-up-down.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/disclosure/grey-disclosure-arrow-up-down.png), linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  background-position: 95% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #333;
  cursor: default;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 29px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 72px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 7px 19px 7px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .01px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: '';
  white-space: nowrap;  
  padding:0;
}

.dd-option {
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 30px 6px 8em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: none !important;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/5c1eca60c927766ada5eb54b137ea6dd4ccffbea/jquery.ddslick.min.js"></script>

<select name="selector" id="demoSelector">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also dropdown seems a bit laggy